# Autostart GlassFish4 on boot on CentOS 7 minimal install

Tags: centos7, systemd, glassfish

I've installed GlassFish 4 on one of my virtual machines which is CentOS 7 with minimal install. I want to start GlassFish when I start the virtual machine.

I've created `/usr/lib/systemd/system/glassfish4.service`, which contains:

```
[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/opt/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I ran the command to add it to start automatically:

```
sudo systemctl enable glassfish4.service
```

But when I start the virtual machine, nothing happens. GlassFish does not run. What should I do to run it on boot?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the server.log suggest anything? Does GlassFish start correctly if you run the `systemctl` command manually?